# jquery callback not working

Tags: jquery

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong in this jquery script?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("a.book").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().next('div').slideToggle('slow', function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('bookopen');
        });
    });
});
```

I want the div to toggle, and then afterwards I want the element `$a.book` to change to `$a.bookopen`. But when I write the code above the toggle doesn't work. If I remove the callback function `toggleClass` the the `slideToggle` works just fine.

Any ideas? I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `this` reference in the inner callback is to the `div` that's being toggled, not the `a` that triggered it.  You could close over a reference to it,

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("a.book").click(function() {
        var $a = $(this);
        $(this).parent().next('div').slideToggle('slow', function(){
            $a.toggleClass.('bookopen');
        });
    });
});
```

or you could navigate back to it from jQuery methods from the div:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("a.book").click(function() {
        $a.parent().next('div').slideToggle('slow', function(){
            $(this).prev('whatever').find('a.book').toggleClass('bookopen');
        });
    });
});
```

Note that this depends on the element structure.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the reference to `this` is not what you want for the callback function.  Set a breakpoint on that line to check.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the changes harpo mentioned, I think this line of code:

```
$a.toggleClass.('bookopen');
```

should be this:

```
$a.toggleClass('bookopen');
```

Comment: You should add this as a comment to his post.

Comment: @Brad.  I posted as an answer before I saw harpo's post (ours were only 1 minute apart) and then edited my post later to refer to his.